# The first cohomology of group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

I would like to ask if G is a group of order $p^4 (p\neq 2)$ as form $C_{p^3}\rtimes C_p$ (a semidirect product of cyclic group of order $p^3$ by a group of order $p$). Then can we obtain the first co-homology $H^1(C_p,C_{p^3} )$?
Is there any upper bound on the order of $H^1(C_p, C_{p^3})$?

yours,

Comment: (If you want cohomology, you should put the index as an *upper* index lest the wrath of the Gods Of Notation fall upon thee)

Comment: Do you want the action on $C_p$ to be trivial? Do you want the cohomology of what group? You mention $G$ in the first sentence byt in the end you ask about the cohomology of $C_{p^3}$...

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean $H^1(C_p,C_{p^3})$, which would correspond to the conjugacy classes of complements in the semidirect product? If so, then the answer depends on the action of $C_p$ on $C_{p^3}$.

Comment: Your edit did not clarify what role the group G plays in your question.

Comment: G is a group of order $p^4$ and exponent $p^3$.

Comment: You have still not explained what is the connection between the group $G$ and your question about a cohomology group.

Answer (score 1):

There must be a mistake in your notation. Cohomology *groups* $H^r$(G, A) are defined only for a group G and a G-module A, i.e. an *abelian* group A on which G acts. If A is not abelian, one can still define $H^1$(G, A) in certain cases,  but it is just a *set* (see Serre's "Galois Cohomology", chapter 3).

If your $H^1$ notation means that the semi-direct product acts trivially on $C_p$ , then the inflation-restriction exact sequence (= beginning of the Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence) should do the job.